# Build Failed, Exception Message: The values provided for the root activity's arguments did not satisfy the root activity's requirements.

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild

Build is failing with below Exception and how to debug these kinds of errors ?

TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition xxxxx: 
Exception Message: The values provided for the root activity's arguments did not satisfy the root activity's requirements:
'DynamicActivity': Expected an input parameter value of type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.BuildVerbosity' for parameter named 'Verbosity'.
Parameter name: rootArgumentValues (type ArgumentException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Validation.ActivityValidationServices.ValidateRootInputs(Activity rootActivity, IDictionary`2 inputs)
   at System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstance.InitializeCore(IDictionary`2 workflowArgumentValues, IList`1 workflowExecutionProperties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was build definition level changes, Changing Build Verbosity to "minimal" worked fine.

[image]

Comment: Mark it as answer once you can, so it will be beneficial to other community members who have similar issue.